# Правильное написание окончания в стихе

Tags: окончания

*Руки, горечью утомлённые,

Опускались в воды бездонные

Зачерпнуть ещё пророчества,

Не противясь одиночеству/одиночеством.*

Comment: Противиться - чему? - одиночеству. При чем тут стих?

Comment: Возможно, автор имел в виду "в приведенном стихотворном тексте". Это же новый участник, у него еще мало опыта в оформлении вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре указан обязательный **дательный падеж:** противиться (чему?) одиночеству.

ПРОТИВИТЬСЯ,  Оказывать противодействие, сопротивляться **кому-, чему-л.** П. уговорам, сну.

Сравнить:

ТЯГОТИТЬСЯ,  **кем-чем**. Испытывать чувство неудобства, скованности, обременительности. **Т. одиночеством.**

Answer (score 1):

Руки не могут быть утомлены горечью. Более того, руками (даже зело утомлёнными) пророчеств не почерпнёшь. И уже тем более руки одиночеству не противятся (если только автор не намекает на рукоблудие).

Этот стишок не подлежит исправлению.

Comment: Здесь переносный смысл, называется "развернутая метафора". Можно, к примеру,  представить, что одинокий человек ищет мудрости и  утешения в книгах. Но в любом случае надо прочитать всё стихотворение, прежде чем судить о нем.

Comment: @Sharon : Увы, вижу здесь лишь красивость ради красивости, изысканность ради изысканности, стихотворную технику ради техники. Когда-нибудь хорошо тренированные компьютеры сумеют писать подобные вторичные вирши.